# how can i access a variable of type stringbuilder from another class?

Tags: c#, struct, stringbuilder

im new to c# and still learning, im not sure if i was correct to put this inside a struct, i want to access automotivedevice in another class to print out its information. How do i do this?

ive tried changing it from a struct to a class, i also made sure to instance the struct in the other class

````
```  struct car
    {
        public void StringBuilder()
        {
            StringBuilder automotivedevice = new StringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine("enter brand of the car");
            StringBuilder CarBrand = automotivedevice.AppendLine(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("enter mileage of the car");
            StringBuilder CarMileage = automotivedevice.AppendLine(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("enter number of cylinders in the car");
            StringBuilder NumberOfCylinders = automotivedevice.AppendLine(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }```
````

Comment: You hand the other class this instance of the car struct. The only other way is global variables. But we really should never use global variables to share data. It is just a bad idea.

Comment: @DourHighArch: I think you are missreading his poor naming. The function is called `StringBuilder` but it should be called `getUserInput` or something like that. And honestly it does not even belong into car - this is a console only way to get the data from the user. It does not belong into a data class. Of course the more we look at it, the more it looks like a XY Problem at the end of a chain of XY problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // collect all user input
        Console.WriteLine("enter brand of car...");
        string brandInput = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("enter mileage of car...");
        string mileageInput = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("enter number of cylinders in the car...");
        string cylinderCountInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // create instance of car and assign user input to car properties
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.Brand = brandInput;
        myCar.Mileage = mileageInput;
        myCar.NumberOfCylinders = cylinderCountInput;

        // output values in the car object to the console window
        Console.WriteLine("Brand: " + myCar.Brand);
        Console.WriteLine("Mileage: " + myCar.Mileage);
        Console.WriteLine("Cylinder Count: " + myCar.NumberOfCylinders);

        Console.WriteLine("press <ENTER> to close the console window");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}


public class Car
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Mileage { get; set; }
    public string NumberOfCylinders { get; set; }
}
```